Twitter api in laravel with abraham/twitteroauth package
the code gives me 404 notfound error despite i am following the documentation, when i go to this endpoint account/verify_credentials
but work fine if i go to this endpoint for example : users/{$user->social_id}/tweets
so is the problem with code below or the endpoint is incorrect and what endpoint i go to to get user twitter info
this is full code :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function fetchTwitterProfile()
    {
        // Set your access token details
        $user = User::find(94);
        $accessToken = $user->access_token;
        $accessTokenSecret = $user->refresh_token;

        // Initialize TwitterOAuth with your app credentials and the user's access tokens
        $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(
            config('services.twitter.client_id'),
            config('services.twitter.client_secret'),
            $accessToken,
            $accessTokenSecret
        );
        try {
            $userInfo = $twitter->get('account/verify_credentials', [
                'include_email' => 'true',
                'skip_status' => 'true',
                'include_entities' => 'false'
            ]);

            if ($twitter->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
                return $userInfo;
            } else {
                return "Error: " . $twitter->getLastHttpCode() . " - " . $twitter->getLastBody();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    
      
    }

}

note : the credentials of app is correct and token of user are correct as i get them after he sign in in my application

Possibly because of API version or permissions. Note that you need to use another endpoint for API v1.1, for example: account/verify_credentials, and access token should include required permissions. Also, you can log an error response for better debugging. If you're using the Twitter API v2 version, then endpoint structure is totally different - for example, users/{user_id}.

okey where i can get the endpoints for twitter api v2
